# FCM Cloud Messaging no longer registering new topics

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I have two scripts - one in my iOS/Android app and one on my server.  Both use different libraries for subscribing user tokens to existing and new topics.  Recently, all new topics stopped being registered and I can't figure out why.

In both the App and from my server I get no error when subscribing a users to topics.

In the app I am using `cordova-plugin-firebasex` - specifically the `window.FirebasePlugin.subscribe(topicID)` and on the server I am using the php-fcm library.  I store the users device/token on my server and pull from the mysql database for these types of topics:

```
$client = new \Fcm\FcmClient($serverKey,$senderID) ;
$subscribe = new \Fcm\Topic\Subscribe($topicID);
$subscribe->addDevice($deviceID);
$response = $client->send($subscribe) ;
if (isset($response['results'][0]['error'])) {
  $status = "Error: " .$response['results'][0]['error'] ;
  $eveBC++ ;
} else {
  $status = "Added! - " ;
  $eveGC++ ;
}
echo "\n\t\tEvent Topic: " .$eventID. " - " .$status ;
```

It looks like everything is working as I am not getting any connection/auth errors.  On the server, when an device/token that is pulled from the db no longer exists or is invalid, the above php code returns an FCM error: `Error: NOT_FOUND` which tells me my communications with google and trying to register users for topics is working.  However, after 24hours (and then some) none of the new topics are created.  And on the server, a successful subscribe simply returns:

Using var_dump($response):

```
array(1) {
  ["results"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

To me this is just bad google coding, it should return SOMETHING, not just a bunch of empty results....I mean, at least say "TRUE", "SUCCESS", "ADDED" - or "NEW GROUP DETECTED - Creating Topic and Adding user".

Unfortunately, I have not found a way for the FirebaseX plugin to show me a `subscribe` response.  However, the above code and the app code all seemed to work about 2 weeks ago and, that I can recall, nothing has really changed on either app or server script.

I would figure if my serverKey/senderID were incorrect it would throw an error on connecting to FCM (and I did validated both in the FCM project `cloud messaging` settings.  Or if the App were not properly connecting to Firebase I would see errors in the logs, but all app debugging shows when the app initializes that FCM communication has been established, it grabs/refreshes the users device/token, and if its changed since last time the user opened the app then update the server db with the new token.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question so anyone in the future who comes across this frustrating FCM inconsistency will have an answer to their problem.

My code was never broken.  Because there is no way in FCM to view existing Topics or all the deviceIDs registered to a topic, I was using the FCM project `Cloud Messaging` page that allows you to Send Notifications.  In that Send Notification form is an option to send a message/notification to a `topic`.  When I scroll through the listed topics NONE of the newly created topics show up there - even after 72+ hours of waiting for them to show up.  Thus I kept thinking my new topics weren't being created.

That form is misleading...it has a bunch of my old topics listed, but none of the new ones I have been creating over the last 3 weeks (new topic naming format).  Thus, you can't rely on this form to show you all the topicIDs that you have created.